# How to create actionbar tab navigation in gridView?

Tags: android, list, android-actionbar

If I add tab with simple actionbar tab navigation, when I add more than 10 tabs, it's shows tabs in list.

How to set, if action bar have more than 2 tabs, it shows tabs in list;
and how to change listView to gridView, set some image on item?

GridView item1 is tab1, item2 is tab2, item3 is tab3, etc, in there can click on item2 for open tab2, click on item3 for tab3. And there can add and remove tabs, like it's possible in action bar tab navigation.

It's like in opera mini browser.

Comment: You need to structure your question in a more understandable way. It is not very readable. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want create tab navigation like opera mini browser. Is it possible with action bar??

Comment: Can you edit your question to reflect what you want to achieve?